# How to apply a visual filter to what I am drawing?

Tags: c++, rendering, sfml, color, filtering

I'm looking to apply a sepia filter to what I'm rendering. Perhaps we could just apply the filter to the view or pass it to the draw method to draw everything with the filter (I'm using one draw method, everything that is visible gets drawn by one draw system).

Would I use a shader for this? I honestly don't know how to implement shaders or how to learn.

I'm using sfml.

How would you apply other filters, not just sepia? For example greyscale, moonlight (I would love this one), or the other filter styles you commonly see on the photo editing section of your (i)phone?

I've done some research into it and didn't really find anything useful. However, I assume you use shaders - but I don't really know how to program a shader, so I'll have to learn that if that's the case.

Thanks :)

Comment: Searching "sfml shader" turns up some [tutorials](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-shader.php) and [examples](http://www.glusoft.com/tuto/SFML-shader-example.php), and I get lots of examples when searching for "sepia shader glsl" too. Have you tried working your way through some of these existing resources? Is there a particular step in a tutorial or application of the documentation where you're feeling stuck, that we could use to focus answers more specifically to where you need help?